# Laravel + MySQL multi-level Exists condition not being respected

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel

I'm having a problem with multi-level `whereHas` because the restriction / condition of `city` is not being respected & the query returns all records.

**I know I'm performing an unnecessary nested** `whereHas`, I know I could simplify the query, yet, I'm trying to understand why doesn't it work.

My eloquent query (doesn't work - returns all the results, ignores the `city` condition) - [**See SQLFiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bqfz8Ac8bbBZRiU1ibD2G/1):

```
$teachersStudents = TeachersStudents::whereHas('teacher', function($query)
{
    $query->where('subscription_id', 1)
        ->where('school_id', 11)
        ->whereHas('students', function($subQuery)
        {
            $subQuery->whereHas('student', function($subSubQuery)
            {
                $subSubQuery->whereIn('city', ['Milan'])
                    ->whereNotNull('city');
            });
        });
})
->get();
```

Which translates to:

```
select 
  `teachers_students`.* 
from 
  `teachers_students` 
where 
  exists (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      `teachers` 
    where 
      `teachers_students`.`teacher_id` = `teachers`.`id` 
      and `subscription_id` = 1 
      and `school_id` = 11
      and exists (
        select 
          * 
        from 
          `teachers_students` 
        where 
          `teachers`.`id` = `teachers_students`.`teacher_id` 
          and exists (
            select 
              * 
            from 
              `students` 
            where 
              `teachers_students`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
              and `city` in ('Milan') 
              and `city` is not null
          )
      )
  )
```

The simpler version (works - restricts the `city`) - [**See SQLFiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7SKgG3yGiTuHER7tFSWYUK/0):

```
$teachersStudents = TeachersStudents::whereHas('teacher', function($query)
{
    $query->where('subscription_id', 1)
        ->where('school_id', 11);
})
->whereHas('student', function($query)
{
    $query->whereIn('city', ['Milan'])
        ->whereNotNull('city');
})
->get();
```

Which translates to:

```
select 
  `teachers_students`.* 
from 
  `teachers_students` 
where 
  exists (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      `teachers` 
    where 
      `teachers_students`.`teacher_id` = `teachers`.`id` 
      and `subscription_id` = 1 
      and `school_id` = 11
  ) 
  and exists 
  (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      `students` 
    where 
      `teachers_students`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
      and `city` in ('Milan') 
      and `city` is not null
  )
```

Why does the first query does not respect the `city` field?

Comment: Probably a simple `JOIN` of the 3 tables would be more straightforward and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling teacher student table two times in you whereHas query.
Let's try to understand from bottom to top.

At innermost block, it will filter correctly and will return only student with city 'Milan'

```
        $subQuery->whereHas('student', function($subSubQuery)
        {
            $subSubQuery->whereIn('city', ['Milan'])
                ->whereNotNull('city');
        });
```

At this point querying again to teacher students table which will return, both the records, with student city 'Milan', and with those with not 'Milan' why ?

We are saying to check if the student with city Milan(which inner block returns) exists along with the students with city not 'Milan'.

```
     $query->where('subscription_id', 1)
    ->where('school_id', 11)
    // here all the students along with Milan.
    ->whereHas('students', function($subQuery)
    {
       // here we get students with city Milan correctly.
        $subQuery->whereHas('student', function($subSubQuery)
        {
            $subSubQuery->whereIn('city', ['Milan'])
                ->whereNotNull('city');
        });
    })
;
```

So final solution inner students ->whereHas('students') query shouldn't exist.

At your translated query if you try modifying something like this it will return correct result.

```
select `teachers_students`.* from `teachers_students` 
where exists (
select * from `teachers` 
  where `teachers_students`.`teacher_id` = `teachers`.`id` 
  and `subscription_id` = 1 
  and `school_id` = 11

 /*this is unnecessary and will not work.
  and exists (
    select * from `teachers_students` 
    where `teachers`.`id` = `teachers_students`.`teacher_id` 
    and exists(
        select *from `students` 
        where `teachers_students`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
        and `city` in ('Milan') 
        and `city` is not null
    )
)*/

//adding like this will work and filter correctly.
and exists (
select *from `students` 
        where `teachers_students`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
        and `city` in ('Milan') 
        and `city` is not null
 )
)
```

Hope this should help in understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this will help you understand your problem, but here goes.

Working from the inside to the outside:

1. Get all `students` in Milan (students.id 1)
2. Get all `teachers_students` records for students.id = 1 (teachers_students.id 1)
3. Get all `teachers` records for teachers.id 1 (teachers.id 1)
4. Get all `teachers_students` records for teachers.id 1 (teachers_students.id 1 & 2)

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kqu2YDVN)